# Opensource Mac OSX dock animation in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, dock

I am looking for an open source implementation of the Mac OSX dock animation in objective-c. This is what I am looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That effect is called magnification, you'll have better luck searching for that. Anyway you can try:

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dock-like-animation

https://github.com/livv/fishEye